# Save ODBC credentials for Oracle on Windows

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, oracle-11g, odbc

On my dev machine (Mint Linux), I have ODBC set up with credentials so that I only have to specify `DRIVER` and `DBQ` in the connection string. Unfortunately, the script will have to run on a Windows machine. How do I set it up in Windows so that I don't have to pass in an explicit username and password?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Administrative Tools> Data Sources (ODBC) and create your DSN, either User, System or File... whichever you need.

Answer (score 0):

On your Windows server, set up the ODBC connection there.
Administrative Tools>Data Sources (ODBC)
I usually set these up under System DSN. Pretty straightforward - enter credentials/connection info/etc to include user/pass. It allows you test the connection as well. This stays resident, so when you run the Windows script, the connection is already established and no u/p string needs to be resent.